# Passar datatable para storedprocedure com dapper .net core

Tags: .net-core, dapper

Tenho uma proc com os seguintes parametros

```
 @TabelaIdsCompras TipoTabelaIdGenerico READONLY,  
 @TabelaIdsProds TipoTabelaIdGenerico READONLY
```

E tenho meus datatables:

```
DataTable tableIdsProd= new DataTable();
tableIdsProd.Columns.Add("IdGenerico");
idsSkus.ForEach(id => tableIdsProd.Rows.Add(id.ToString()));

DataTable tableIdsCompra = new DataTable();
tableIdsCompra.Columns.Add("IdGenerico");
idsCompras.ForEach(id => tableIdsCompra.Rows.Add(id.ToString()));
```

Porem nao consigo com o dapper passar um tipo tabela para a procedure nao tem opção igual com o sqldbtype :

```
command.AddInParameter("TabelaIdsCompras", SqlDbType.Structured, tableIdsCompra);
```

Existe alguma solução para passar estes datatables para a proc com dapper ?

Comment: Por que você deseja passar um `DataTable` como parâmetro? Pergunto isso pois talvez exista outra solução para seu problema.

Comment: Entao cara, o "padrao" da empresa e exucutar procs no banco, esse proc seria para verificação de dados ja existentes porem nao posso ficar batenta varias vezes na proc por questoes de performance, pois será uma quantidade rasoavel de dados que serão verificados, a ideia era montar o datatable com os ids que preciso verificar no banco, ou seja passaria dois arrays (no formato do datatable), e na proc eu leria desta tabela. e nao posso fazer essa verificação direto no codigo pois se mudar algo na forma de verificar as duplicidades e mais facil alterar a proc do que subir o codigo pro servidor.